# FB.ui app request goes to a 4oh4.php error page when user clicks accept, how to fix?

Tags: facebook, fb.ui, apprequests

I have a bit of code to let users invite their friends to my site. It looks like this:

```
$('#invite').click(function () {
    FB.ui({ method: 'apprequests', message: "Check out ... great service ...!" });
});
```

When the user clicks the invite button, it pops up the apprequests dialog fine. The user selects some friends, and clicks "send requests".

However, when their friends (under apps requests) click the "Accept" button, it goes to http://www.facebook.com/4oh4.php

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is logged as a [bug](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/204664672932552?browse=search_4e73d1474dee33373887551) with Facebook.  One user suggests setting the "bookmark" property in the advanced app settings to the desired destination URL.